# Nested SWT message box giving error

Tags: java, junit, swt, messagebox

```
public class MesssageBoxQuestionIconYESNOButton {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);

    //This is added to be able to run JUnit in this java class
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result;

    int style = SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;


    MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(shell, style);
    messageBox.setMessage("Would you like to start the test?");
    int rc = messageBox.open();

    if(rc == SWT.YES)
    {
          //Must add in the .class else it will not work
          result = junit.run(testMyCode.class);

         //This part is to ask if the user want to repeat the test again
          Display display1 = new Display();
          Shell shell1 = new Shell(display);

          int style1 = SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;

          MessageBox messageBox1 = new MessageBox(shell, style);
          messageBox1.setMessage("Would you like to repeat the test?");
          int rc1 = messageBox.open();

          if(rc1 == SWT.YES)
          {
              result = junit.run(testMyCode.class);
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox messageBox2 = new MessageBox(shell, style);
              messageBox2.setMessage("Thank You For Using");
              display1.dispose();
          }
    }
    else
    {
        display.dispose();
    }
}
}
```

This is the code that I currently have.
So this is what i want to do:

1. Ask the user if they want to start the test
2. If yes, run the JUnit test
3. After the JUnit test completed. Ask the user if they want to repeat the test again

So in this code, everything is working fine until the 3rd step.

This are the errors that I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone help me to see what is wrong? Thank you

Comment: You should only ever create a single `Display`

Comment: So meaning it shares one single display?

Comment: A normal SWT application only ever creates a single `Display` object which is used for everything. You can never create a second display object on the same thread and on some platforms (macOS for example) it is not possible to create a second display object at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by creating a new `Display`... (Which was never used, BTW.)
I made a few modification, too, so try something like this:

```
public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell( display );

    // This is added to be able to run JUnit in this java class
    final JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result;

    final int style = SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;

    final MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox( shell, style );
    messageBox.setMessage( "Would you like to start the test?" );
    int rc = messageBox.open();

    if ( rc == SWT.YES )
    {
        // Must add in the .class else it will not work
        result = junit.run(testMyCode.class);

        // This part is to ask if the user want to repeat the test again
        final MessageBox messageBox1 = new MessageBox( shell, style );
        messageBox1.setMessage( "Would you like to repeat the test?" );
        rc = messageBox1.open();

        if ( rc == SWT.YES )
        {
            result = junit.run(testMyCode.class);
        }
        int style1 = SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.OK;
        final MessageBox messageBox2 = new MessageBox( shell, style1 );
        messageBox2.setMessage( "Thank You For Using" );
        messageBox2.open();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I just tried, but it does not seems to work. It only shows the first message box, the second message box was not shown.

Comment: Same thing, still not showing the second message box

Comment: But i tried running too, but then it always does not show the second message box. Only after changing to rc1, then it works

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell( display );

    // This is added to be able to run JUnit in this java class
    final JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result;

    final int style = SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.YES | SWT.NO;

    final MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox( shell, style );
    messageBox.setMessage( "Would you like to start the test?" );
    int rc = messageBox.open();

    if ( rc == SWT.YES )
    {
        // Must add in the .class else it will not work
        result = junit.run(testMyCode.class);

        // This part is to ask if the user want to repeat the test again
        final MessageBox messageBox1 = new MessageBox( shell, style );
        messageBox1.setMessage( "Would you like to repeat the test?" );
        int rc2 = messageBox1.open();

        if ( rc2 == SWT.YES )
        {
            result = junit.run(testMyCode.class);
        }
        else
        {
        int style1 = SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.OK;
        final MessageBox messageBox2 = new MessageBox( shell, style1 );
        messageBox2.setMessage( "Thank You For Using" );
        messageBox2.open();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

You need to change the rc as well

Comment: But it only works after changing the second part to rc2. Else, the second message box does not come out.